# Quartz with Spring not commiting

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz, Spring with Hibernate as the JPA provider. Database is Oracle.

I've got a method which writes a file to the file system and update the database with the details.
This method can be called in two ways:

1. Using a web service
2. Or, as a scheduled quatrz job.

I've set up quartz as:

```
<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false" scope="singleton">
        <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
        <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
        <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="quartzProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">FileScheduler</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">6000</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">${driverDelegateClass}</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">5</prop>
                <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This method is using spring managed transaction.

Problem is when this method is invoked by the quartz scheduler, the file gets created but the database is not updated (there should be two tables updated and one table insert).

I've enabled hibernate show_SQL as well, but in case of scheduler no update\insert statements are getting logged.

Though this works fine when this method is invoked by a web service request. Log shows update\insert statements as well.

**UPDATE 1**

To summarize my problem, this is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Create a new record in the employee table.
2. Save the employee_id in the job_store (quartz).
3. When trigger is fired, quartz gives back the employee_id
4. Retrieve (load) the employee record based on this key.
5. Send Employee an email
6. Update the Notification with status as 'Sent' (insert statement)

In the end, I expect all the tables to be updated.

When quartz triggers the job, all is working **except point 6**.
Code is correct as when I invoke this method using a web service call, the table is getting updated.

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the code to use

```
<prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore</prop>
```

but this also doest'nt help.

Please help. Thanks.
Adi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz runs in its own context, even if started by the Spring convenience methods, so you actually don't end up getting your whole Spring application context, unless you explicitly at a `JobDataMap` to pass in beans (see http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?76974-Why-autowired-doesn-t-work-on-a-QuartzJobBean-bean).  So, you can pass in Spring-managed beans, but it all seems kind of messy if you don't need the full capabilities of Quartz.

If your scheduling needs aren't that complex, you might want to consider using the `@Scheduled` Spring annotation ([see here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)), as then the entire method call happens natively in the Spring context, and your transactions will then work as they do in the web service call.

Comment: thanks but the jobs are getting retrieved correctly from the database by the scheduler. JobMap contains the primayKey of the 'User'  table and the User class is populated after the load invocation using this key. It is 'merge' that is not working. That's why I said I can not see the 'insert' SQL in the logs. I can see all the correct 'select' statements.

Comment: I agree with Aaron but if you still want to use quartz ensure  Entitymanager correctly passed to quartz job.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two points to check:

- The data source must be a non-XA data source. If you are using a connection pool from a Java EE application server, chances are high that you have a XA data source. Either configure that data source to be non-XA (if your application setup and server allow that) or create a second, non-XA data source and pass it into the `nonTransactionalDataSource` property. One little gotcha if you use the `nonTransactionalDataSource` property - remember to keep the `dataSource` property set. You cannot define a `nonTransactionalDataSource` without setting the (transactional) `dataSource` as well.
- Make sure your code really runs in a Spring transaction. Have your beans injected into the Quartz job using the `schedulerContextAsMap` property of the `SchedulerFactoryBean`. If you run code that is annotated with `@Transactional` it needs to be autowired. If you hard-code the instantiation of that bean, Spring will not be able to apply the `@Transactional` annotation and silently ignore it.

Also, remove the `org.quartz.jobStore.class` property. The `SchedulerFactoryBean` will override that setting in any case. It puts a `LocalDataSourceJobStore` and it may get confusing if newer versions of the factory decide to put something else.

Last but not least I am wondering if you may have overlooked any exceptions being logged somewhere? Make sure you are monitoring all Spring log messages and all error messages from your application server.

Answer (score -4):

Try `@Transactional` Annotation. (see. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)