# Nullpointer exception quartz integration with spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

am working on a spring hibernate project
Am am trying to connect to the database and get the values from the quartzjob. but i am getting a null pointer exception. Whent i tried to use a ApplicationContext object and get the bean it is connecting to the database.why am not able to do the other way

```
public class JobScheduler extends QuartzJobBean {
    @Autowired
    private SourceDaoImpl sourceDao;
    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setClientKey(300);

        sourceDao.getSourceByClient(client); **//error**
    }
    public SourceDaoImpl getSourceDao() {
        return sourceDao;
    }
    public void setSourceDao(SourceDaoImpl sourceDao) {
        this.sourceDao = sourceDao;
    }
}
```

this is my applicationcontext.xml

```
<!-- scheduler -->
<bean id="jobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTriggerjobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobScheduler" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/10 * * * * ?" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jobScheduler" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerjobScheduler" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobClass"
    class="com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler">

</bean>
```

this is the exception

```
ERROR 04-06 07:22:55,009 - Job DEFAULT.jobScheduler threw an unhandled Exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler.executeInternal(JobScheduler.java:21)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
ERROR 04-06 07:22:55,010 - Job (DEFAULT.jobScheduler threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:227)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler.executeInternal(JobScheduler.java:21)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    ... 1 more
```

hibernate.xml

```
<bean id="sourceInstanceDao" class="com.dca.dao.impl.SourceInstanceDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: I see no configuration to wire the dao class.

Comment: its there i didnt shown that its in a hibernatecontex.xml and am including that file in to the Applicationcontext.xml

Comment: please post that file too

Comment: <bean id="sourceInstanceDao" class="com.vxl.appanalytix.dca.dao.impl.SourceInstanceDaoImpl">
  <property name="sessionFactory">
   <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
  </property>
 </bean> i have this in my hibernatecontext.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quartz runs in its own context, even if started by the Spring convenience methods, so you actually don't end up getting your whole Spring application context, unless you explicitly at a JobDataMap to pass in beans

```
<bean id="jobScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.vxl.appanalytix.dca.scheduling.JobScheduler" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
              <entry key ="sourceDao" value-ref="sourceDao"/>
              <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

my job scheduler class

```
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobContext)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setClientKey(300);
        sourceDao= (SourceDaoImpl) jobContext.getJobDetail()
                .getJobDataMap().get("sourceDao");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, unfortunately, simple: `sourceDao` is null.

Quartz instantiates the job classes by itself. The only way to pass a parameter to that class is to use the `JobExecutionContext` in `executeInternal()`.

First, when you `scheduleJob()` you have to set the `JobDetails`.

```
JobDetail thisJobDetail = new SimpleJobDetail<T>(this.getClass().getName(), (Class<? extends AbstractQuartzJob<T>>) this.getClass());
thisJobDetail.getJobDataMap().put(DATA_MANAGER_MAP_KEY,
                dataManager);

sched.scheduleJob(thisJobDetail ,aTrigger);
```

Then, when you are executing the job, you can access the details like this:

```
this.dataManager = (DataManager) jobContext.getJobDetail()
                                 .getJobDataMap().get(DATA_MANAGER_MAP_KEY);
```

In your case use `sourceDao` as the `dataManager` here.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801048/quartz-with-spring-not-commiting?rq=1) i think this is the problem is there any solution for this